# heroku login give me EAACCESS:permission denied

Tags: heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I have  installed heroku toolbelt but each time I do "heroku login" or any other heroku command like "heroku version"  I get something like :

autoupdate:: 'EACCES': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
▸    '/home/vanessa/.cache/heroku/update.lock.readers.lock'
▸    'EACCES': EACCES: permission denied, open
▸    '/home/vanessa/.cache/heroku/plugins.json'
▸    'EACCES': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
▸    '/home/vanessa/.cache/heroku/update.lock.readers.lock'

I have deleted and reinstalled, I have also done sudo apt-get upgrade heroku to update the CLI, however I still get same results. My OS is Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have permission to access that file. Run `rm -rf /home/vanessa/.cache/heroku` and hopefully it will be recreated with the right permissions.

Answer (score 5):

Check if the directory is owned by the user you're running heroku commands from:

```
ls -l /home/vanessa/.cache/heroku
```

If it's owned by something else like root, and assuming you are running heroku as the user "vanessa", try:

```
sudo chown -R vanessa:vanessa /home/vanessa/.cache/heroku
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 the folder was~/.cache/sfdx where I had the problem after the sfdx CLI install.
So this answer should be ok.

Comment: `namei -l` might be better here than `ls -l`.  `namei -l ~/.cache/heroku` will helpfully give you the ownership/permissions of the heroku folder (if it exists), plus those of any containing folders.
For some reason I had `drwx------ root root .cache`, so I couldn't create any subfolders there.  The fix for that was `chown -R matthew.matthew ~/.cache`

Answer (score 0):

*Follow steps*:

- Uninstall `heroku cli`
- and install the latest version.

That worked for me